# How does Direct mapped cache implement spatial locality?

Tags: caching, memory-management

**An array is declared as floatA[2048] . Each array element is 4Bytes in size.This program is run on a computer that has a
direct mapped data cache of size 8Kbytes, with block (line) size of 16Bytes.
Which elements of the array conflict with element A[0] in the data cache?**

Ultimately A[0],A[512],A[1024],A[1536] map to cache block 0

As per my understanding, when A[0] is required for the first time, A[0],A[1],A[2],A[3](since one cache block can hold 4 elements) are brought into the cache and placed in cache blocks 0, 1, 2,and 3 respectively.

Other approach would be to bring only A[0] and place it in cache block 0. (Spatial locality not used here)

What is the general practice in such a scenario?

Answer (score 0):

All four elements A[3:0] are stored in cache block 0 - since these 4 elements together form 16B. Depending on how the hardware system is set up, the next 16B are then stored on cache block 1 (the decision of which cache line (16B contiguous data granule) maps into which set is made while designing hardware and is based on certain bits of the address.